# How to add custom action to the rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

In my case I need to approve records from the [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) list panel. What I would like to do is to make a link with :remote => true for each record in the list page and using the pointed in the link action approve selected record.

How to do this easily without hacking rails_admin?

Comment: I know this is kind of an old question but I stumbled across it in a google search so I thought I would add this info incase anyone else does the same.

You can now customize actions in rails_admin, and add new actions

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions

Answer (score 2):

As of a couple of weeks ago, [Custom Actions](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action) are now supported in RailsAdmin.

Comment: Eh, already switched to active_admin for all the active projects. No way back to rails_admin... too magical.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for custom actions yet: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/166 . ActiveAdmin (http://activeadmin.info/) seems to be much more customizable (with a totally other approch), I will replace rails_admin with this gem...

Comment: Yes, I wrote there in September... still no answer. So actually that's not an asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to add custom actions, but you cannot do this:

> link with :remote => true

One hacky way is to make the `pretty_value` to show a link with `remote: true`.
That will be shown on /admin/model/:id page, not on the list.